# RXJS: Requests by queue - ForkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to do image upload by the queue. Currently, I need to upload the images by fives

For example, if I have 10 images, I need to upload 5 images and when these 5 will be uploaded I need to do another request for the remaining 5 images.

After a lot of searches and testing a lot of RXJS operators/functions I could find this solution by (`concat` - RXJS function), and (`scan` and `last` - RXJS operators):

**in index.html**

```
// added chunk function into array protptype
 Array.prototype.chunk = function (chunkSize) {
     var R = [];
     for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i += chunkSize) {
        R.push(this.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
     }

     return R;
  }
```

**In the Service**

```js
  uploadImages(images: File[]) {
    const requestsList = images.map(file => {
      return this._baseAPI.filesManagement.uploadFile({ file, 'image' })
    });

      // custom function: added manualy in index.html
      const requestChunks = requestsList.chunk(5);  
 
      const requestsByChunks = requestChunks.map(reqs => forkJoin(reqs));

      return concat(...requestsByChunks).pipe(
         // transforming and collecting all of the responses
          scan((acc, response: {folder: string; image: string}[]) => {
            response.forEach(itemResponse => {
              if (!acc[itemResponse.folder]) { acc[itemResponse.folder] = []; }
              acc[itemResponse.folder].push(itemResponse.image);
            });
            return acc;
          },
            {} as { [key: string]: string }),
          // getting the callected response only once at the end
          last()
       );
  }
```

**Usage example**

```
this.uploadImages(/* Array of files*/).subscribe(response => {console.log(response); })
```

I would know is there any other solution, or best practice for these situations. Maybe I missed out on something because I am not sure this is the best solution for this?

Also: here is the simulation of current logic: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-kcnrgn?file=index.ts

Thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it while leaning a bit more into RxJS and immutable objects/arrays.

Might need some tweaking as I didn't really test this. It's basically the same as what you're doing.

```ts
uploadImages(images: File[]) {
  return from(images).pipe(
    map(file => this._baseAPI.filesManagement.uploadFile({ file, 'image' })),
    // chunk 5
    bufferCount(5), 
    // perform the requests 5 at a time
    concatMap(reqs => forkJoin(reqs)), 
    // like last, but creates an array of emissions (which are themselves arrays of size 5)
    toArray(), 
    // Flatten the array of arrays into a single array with all the results
    map(arr => arr.flat()),
    // transforming all of the responses
    map(res => res.reduce((
        acc: { [key: string]: string[] }, 
        {folder, image}: { folder: string; image: string }
      ) => ({...acc, folder: [...acc[folder] || [], image] }),
      {}
    ))
  );
}
```

Comment: oh great, thank you. let me test this and come back.

Comment: Thank you very much